# Regex default value if not found

Tags: regex, default

I would like to supply my regular expression with a 'default' value, so if the thing I was looking for is not found, it will return the default value as if it had found it.

Is this possible to do using regex?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38579881 shows how to return an empty string as "default" value (in Python)

Comment: Similar to this, I've only been able to come up with having empty strings returned as default aka `(your regex|.{0})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want some sort of regex syntax that says "if the regexp does not match any part of the given string pretend that it matched the following substring: 'foobar'". Such a feature does not exist in any regexp syntax I've seen.

You'll probably need to something like this:

```
matched_string = string.find_regex_match(regex);
if(matched_string == null) {
  string = "default";
}
```

(This will of course need to be adjusted to the language you're using)

Comment: Bugger. I hoped I wouldn't have to do it that way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't do that with RegExp`s, at least with Perl Compatible Regular Expressions.

You can see by your self [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer this without a specific language, but in Perl at least, something like this works:

```
$string='hello';
$default = 1234;
($match) = ($string =~ m/(\d+)/ or $default);
print "$match\n";

1234
```

Not strictly part of the regex, but avoids the extra conditional block.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did in javascript...

```js
function match(regx, str, dflt, index = 0) {
    if (!str) return dflt
    let x = str.match(regx)
    return x ? x[index] || dflt : dflt
}
```