# Return string with first match for a regex, handling case where there is no match

Tags: python, regex, string, index-error

I want to get the first match of a regex.

In the following case, I have a list:

```py
text = 'aa33bbb44'
re.findall('\d+',text)
# ['33', '44']
```

I could extract the first element of the list:

```py
text = 'aa33bbb44'
re.findall('\d+',text)[0]
# '33'
```

But that only works if there is at least one match, otherwise I'll get an `IndexError`:

```py
text = 'aazzzbbb'
re.findall('\d+',text)[0]
# IndexError: list index out of range
```

In which case I could define a function:

```py
def return_first_match(text):
    try:
        result = re.findall('\d+',text)[0]
    except Exception, IndexError:
        result = ''
    return result
```

Is there a way of obtaining that result without defining a new function?

Comment: For me the accepted answer didn't work. I had to remove the array index access and use `len(re.findAll)==0` check instead.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You could embed the `''` default in your regex by adding `|$`:

```
>>> re.findall('\d+|$', 'aa33bbb44')[0]
'33'
>>> re.findall('\d+|$', 'aazzzbbb')[0]
''
>>> re.findall('\d+|$', '')[0]
''
```

Also works with `re.search` pointed out by others:

```
>>> re.search('\d+|$', 'aa33bbb44').group()
'33'
>>> re.search('\d+|$', 'aazzzbbb').group()
''
>>> re.search('\d+|$', '').group()
''
```

Answer (score 85):

If you only need the first match, then use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.regex.search) instead of `re.findall`:

```
>>> m = re.search('\d+', 'aa33bbb44')
>>> m.group()
'33'
>>> m = re.search('\d+', 'aazzzbbb')
>>> m.group()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#281>", line 1, in <module>
    m.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Then you can use `m` as a checking condition as:

```
>>> m = re.search('\d+', 'aa33bbb44')
>>> if m:
        print('First number found = {}'.format(m.group()))
    else:
        print('Not Found')


First number found = 33
```

Answer (score 26):

I'd go with:

```
r = re.search("\d+", ch)
result = r.group(0) if r else ""
```

`re.search` only looks for the *first* match in the string anyway, so I think it makes your intent slightly more clear than using `findall`.

Comment: yes @Bill and `findall` could be critical if the amount of data is very large. waste of resources

Answer (score 12):

You shouldn't be using `.findall()` at all - `.search()` is what you want.  It finds the leftmost match, which is what you want (or returns `None` if no match exists).

```
m = re.search(pattern, text)
result = m.group(0) if m else ""
```

Whether you want to put that in a function is up to you.  It's *unusual* to want to return an empty string if no match is found, which is why nothing like that is built in.  It's impossible to get confused about whether `.search()` on its own finds a match (it returns `None` if it didn't, or an `SRE_Match` object if it did).

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
x = re.findall('\d+', text)
result = x[0] if len(x) > 0 else ''
```

Note that your question isn't exactly related to regex. Rather, how do you safely find an element from an array, if it has none.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would perform a bit better in case greater amount of input data does not contain your wanted piece because except has greater cost.

```
def return_first_match(text):
    result = re.findall('\d+',text)
    result = result[0] if result else ""
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

just assign the results to a variable then iterate the variable

```
 text = 'aa33bbb44'
 result=re.findall('\d+',text)
 for item in result:
     print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

With Assignment expressions (PEP572):

```
text = 'aa33bbb44'
r = m.group() if (m:=re.search(r'\d+',text)) is not None else ''
```

Answer (score 0):

With `re.findall`, you can convert the output into an iterator with `iter()` and call `next()` on it to get the first result. `next()` is particularly useful for this task because a default value (e.g. `''`) can be passed to it; the default is returned if the iterator is empty, i.e. if there are no matches.

```py
next(iter(re.findall('\d+', 'aa33bbb44')), '')      # '33'
next(iter(re.findall('\d+', 'aazzzbbb')), '')       # ''
```

At this point, `next()` can used with `re.finditer` for the job as well.

```py
next(re.finditer('\d+', 'aa33bbb44'), [''])[0]      # '33'
next(re.finditer('\d+', 'aazzzbbb'), [''])[0]       # ''
```

You can also use the walrus operator with `re.search` for a one-liner.

```py
m[0] if (m:=re.search('\d+', 'aa33bbb44')) else ''  # '33'
m[0] if (m:=re.search('\d+', 'aazzzbbb')) else ''   # ''
```

For this specific task, the argument against `re.findall` is performance and, indeed for large strings, the gap is huge. If there are multiple matches, `re.findall` is much, much slower than `re.search` or `re.finditer`<sup>1</sup>. However, if there are no matches, `re.search` with the walrus and `re.finditer` are the fastest.<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Timings for strings with 1mil characters and 100k matches.

```py
text = 'aabbbccc11'*100_000

%timeit m[0] if (m:=re.search('\d+', text)) else ''
# 1.94 µs ± 192 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100,000 loops each)
%timeit next(re.finditer('\d+', text), [''])[0]
# 2.38 µs ± 122 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100,000 loops each)
%timeit next(iter(re.findall('\d+', text)), '')
# 59 ms ± 8.65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit re.search('\d+|$', text)[0]
# 2.32 µs ± 300 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100,000 loops each)
%timeit re.findall('\d+|$', text)[0]
# 82.7 ms ± 1.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)
```

<sup>2</sup> Timings for strings with 1mil characters and no matches.

```py
text = 'aabbbcccdd'*100000

%timeit m[0] if (m:=re.search('\d+', text)) else ''
# 26.3 ms ± 662 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit next(re.finditer('\d+', text), [''])[0]
# 26 ms ± 195 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit next(iter(re.findall('\d+', text)), '')
# 26.2 ms ± 615 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit re.search('\d+|$', text)[0]
# 72.9 ms ± 14.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit re.findall('\d+|$', text)[0]
# 67.8 ms ± 2.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100 loops each)
```