# Performing regex search on a sql query string python 3.x

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I would like to find out if a `select some_col_name, * , some_col_name from table_name` occurs in a query string like example below:

```
select some_col_name, *, some_col_names
from table_name
```

or

```
select some_col_name, 
*, some_col_name
from 
table_name
```

So far, I am only able to match `select some_col_names, *` using

```
re.search("select(\s*.*?)*\*", query_string)
```

How do I match the desired expression? I would like to stop after matching the first occurrence.

Comment: This smacks of an XY problem. Why do you want to do this? It's not that it's impossible, but it's probably not the *right* way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Do you want to find all queries that select `*` as a column?

Comment: Given a query, I want to know if a user tried to select all columns in a specific table_name (using select * as opposed to mentioning the column name). But note that the query string could have multiple select statements because of any use of WITH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
select([^*](?!from))*\*([^*](?!from))* from[\s\r\n]*table_name
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/BKcMmPNojlLaEJ).

This will match over multiple lines, but due to the negative look aheads won’t skip from the `select` of one query to the `from` of a later query.

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian, but I want to also add a specific table name to the match. You example matches only up to from. In addition, I want to only stop at the first occurrence.

Comment: @obiigbe91 I’ve added the table name to the regex. If you want to match only first, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38579883/256196) for how.