# Python 2.7.16 - regex lookbehind not working with Findall

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind

I have the following piece of code
Note: Line variable is from a line in a text file I'm reading and pattern variable is saved in a config file which I pickup and apply in the code

```
line ="[u'INVOICE# SMR/0038 f"', u'', u'', u'']"
pattern ='(?<=(invoice#)\s)[A-z]{3}/\d{1,5}'

regex = re.compile(r'' + pattern),re.IGNORECASE)
invNum= re.findall(pattern, str(line),re.IGNORECASE)[0]
      ........
```

I'm expecting to get `invNum = SMR/0038` but instead I get `invoice#`. What's the issue?
if try this pattern on https://regexr.com/ I see that the lookbehind is working. But transferring it to Python code doesn't work. See image below from https://regexr.com/

[sample from regexr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojrgl.png)

Comment: Is this correct ? ```line ="[u'INVOICE# SMR/0038 f"', u'', u'', u'']"``` I don't think so

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915018/re-findall-behaves-weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`re.findall` returns the captured substring only if there is a capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915018/re-findall-behaves-weird) in the pattern, you get the `invoice#` substring as you wrapped it with a capturing group.

Also, note that [`[A-z]` matches more than just ASCII letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926), it is one of the most confusing patterns in the regex world. Use `[A-Za-z]`.

You need to capture the part you want to extract, you do not even need a lookbehind:

```
import re
line ="[u'INVOICE# SMR/0038 f\"', u'', u'', u'']"
pattern = re.compile('invoice#\s+([A-Za-z]{3}/\d{1,5})', re.I)
print( re.findall(pattern, line) ) # => ['SMR/0038']
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/OWuSOo)

Actually, as you need [to get the first match only, use `re.search`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579725/return-string-with-first-match-regex) (`re.findall` returns all matches):

```
m = pattern.search(line)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # => SMR/0038
```

Comment: Interesting...I always test the pattern on regexr.com and when I use your pattern on that site it returns me Invoice# SMR/0038..the whole thing instead of just the SMR/0038 string ...so what's the difference? Python seems to be doing a lookbehind even when you don't have the lookbehind specified in your pattern

Comment: I wanted to capture the invoice number only if it is preceded by "Invoice#" label..there could be other words before the label...so if "JnJ LLC Invoice# SMT/778"  string is passed I should get SMT/778 after regex is applied

Comment: @AniM You do not need a lookbehind at all when you need a capturing group. The solution works with `JnJ LLC Invoice# SMT/778`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/IbaAef). You only need positive lookbehind when you expect overlapping matches. In other cases, capturing group is enough.