# Regex Not Matching Pattern from BeautifulSoup results

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to parse some HTML to look for a RegEx. When I use online tools to validate my regex expression, it works properly. It finds the value. However, when I use BeautifulSoup with RegEx the pattern fails to find the expression.

I am looking to grab this data: `/some/path/to/file?accountTransactionID=f2448439-ec25-4a61-a6f4-4c6fa0767f19&amp;accountNumber=123456&amp;searchValue=ABC123&amp;isActiveHistory=True`

From this line:

```
 var url = '/some/path/to/file?accountTransactionID=f2448439-ec25-4a61-a6f4-4c6fa0767f19&amp;accountNumber=123456&amp;searchValue=ABC123&amp;isActiveHistory=True'
```

In the below demo html.

Here is the Python script I'm working with. I have used several SO questions, including this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579725/return-string-with-first-match-regex), but have not and any success.

If I use `soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser').find_all(string=PATTERN)` then the full text of the script has been stored in an array. I've tried looping through the array to find the text again, but it always comes up empty.

***What have I done wrong?***

---

**Python:**

```
FILE_PATH = os.getcwd() + '/demo.html'
PATTERN = re.compile('var url = \'(.*?)\'')

with open(FILE_PATH) as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')  # .find_all(string=PATTERN)
    data = PATTERN.match(str(soup))
    print(f'Data: {data}')
    # for script in soup:
    #     print(script)
    #     data = PATTERN.match(str(script))
    #     if data is not None:
    #         print(f'Data: {data}')
    #     else:
    #         print('NO DATA FOUND')
```

Outputs: **Data: None**

---

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="/some/path/1"></script>
    <script src="/some/path/2"></script>
    <script src="/some/path/31"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function downloadFile() {
            var readyToDownload = 'f2448439-ec25-4a61-a6f4-4c6fa0767f19';
            if (readyToDownload !== '')
            {
                var url = '/some/path/to/file?accountTransactionID=f2448439-ec25-4a61-a6f4-4c6fa0767f19&amp;accountNumber=123456&amp;searchValue=ABC123&amp;isActiveHistory=True'
                url = url.replace(/&amp;/g, "&")
                window.open(url, '_blank');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup isn't really doing much help for this. BeautifulSoup.find() or findall() will return the element that contains the text which in this case is a `<script>` element.

Just match the whole text from the file and call search() instead of match() on the pattern. The match() function starts matching the characters at the beginning of string so will not find a match.

Try this:

```python
with open(FILE_PATH) as fp:
    html = fp.read()
m = PATTERN.search(html)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
/some/path/to/file?accountTransactionID=f2448439-ec25-4a61-a6f4-4c6fa0767f19&amp;accountNumber=123456&amp;searchValue=ABC123&amp;isActiveHistory=True
```