# call a method only if the previous one returned a value

Tags: python

I am looking for a specific string in text, and want to get it only if found.

I can write it as followד and it works:

```py
if re.search("Counter=(\d+)", line):
  total = int(re.search("Counter=(\d+)", line).group(1))
else:
  total = 1
```

But I remember another nicer way to write it with question mark before the "group", and put value "1" as default value in case of `re.search` return an empty result.

Comment: *question mark before something* that's not Python

Comment: Do you mean `int(re.search("Counter=(\d+)", line)?.group(1))`? that's C# syntax, and will check for `null(None)` value only. You could define `total = 1` before the `if` and drop the `else`.

Comment: Does this help? if total := int(re.search("Counter=(\d+)", line).group(1))
    total = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.findall) it will return a list with groups or empty.
Then you can conditionally assign based on this list using a [ternary expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator):

```
counters = re.findall("Counter=(\d+)", line)
total = counters[0] if counters else 1
```

(This will also work in Python before 3.8.)

Test with both cases:

```
counters = re.findall("Counter=(\d+)", 'Hello World')
total = counters[0] if counters else 1
print(total)
# 1

counters = re.findall("Counter=(\d+)", 'Counter=100')
total = counters[0] if counters else 1
print(total)
# 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Python 3.8 or later, you can assign to the output of `re.search` in the `if` statement with the walrus-operator `:=`.

```
if match := re.search("Counter=(\d+)", line):
   total = int(match.group(1))
else:
   total = 1
```

If you want a oneliner:

```
total = int(match.group(1)) if (match := re.search("Counter=(\d+)", line)) else 1
```

Comment: I had Python 3.7.4 and I upgraded it to latest python, but vsCode still thinks my python is the older release. How can I fix it? (in windows cmd "python --version" displays the latest python release.

Comment: I found that I can select the python 3.10 via "view" -> command pallet, but now there is a new problem:import xlsxwriter and pandas doesn't work :(

Comment: For legacy Python (below 3.8) see the [findall with ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72815661/5730279) implementation.

Comment: @אלישבע you can still use the same code if you use another line to assign `match = re.search("Counter=(\d+)", line)` beforehand.

Comment: @אלישבע the problem in your comment here is simple - by changing the version you don't have libraries installed for other versions. Simply install again for the proper Python (pip) version

Answer (score -1):

You could [match the empty end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38579881/12671057) and replace by 1 then:

```
total = int(re.search("Counter=(\d+)|$", line)[1] or 1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRKEolYsrLb9IISczL1UhM09B3Tm/NK8ktcjWxEhdR0E9LT9f3YpLoSS/JDFHwRaooESjKFWvODWxKDlDQwmmViMmRVuzRkVJB2yMZrRhrALQSENNLoWCIpAWsHbN//8B)